# ERROR at line 1: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933

i'm working on a request ,and i think i missed a clause because i having this error 
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

the request :

```
echo "update account_balances_t set credit_limit='51200' inner join account_t on account_t.poid_id0=account_balances_t.obj_id0  where access_code1 in (SELECT DISTINCT ACCESS_CODE1,REC_ID FROM  ACCOUNT_T A, ACCOUNT_PRODUCTS_T AP WHERE A.STATUS != 10103  AND A.ACCESS_CODE1 IS NOT NULL AND A.POID_ID0 = AP.OBJ_ID0 AND AP.PRODUCT_OBJ_ID0 = (SELECT POID_ID0 FROM PRODUCT_T WHERE NAME = 'IEW - Europe Daily Plan 1')); "|sqlplus -s `whoami`/`whoami`@$ORACLE_SID
```

the error :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ACCESS_CODE1,REC_ID FROM  ACCOUNT_T A, ACCOUNT_PRODUCTS_T AP WHERE A.STATUS != 10103  AND A.ACCESS_CODE1 IS NOT NULL AND A.POID_ID0 = AP.OBJ_ID0 AND AP.PRODUCT_OBJ_ID0 = (SELECT POID_ID0 FROM PRODUCT_T WHERE NAME = 'IEW - Europe Daily Plan 1'))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically have this:

```
UPDATE account_balances_t
SET credit_limit='51200'
INNER JOIN account_t ON account_t.poid_id0=account_balances_t.obj_id0
WHERE access_code1 IN (...);
```

I can't find anything similar among the [available syntax variations for `UPDATE`](http://psoug.org/reference/update.html).

Also, you're attempting to match column `access_code1` with a subquery that returns *two* columns.

Answer (score 0):

> update account__balances_t set credit_limit='51200' **inner join** account_t on .....

Syntax is bad - oracle doesn't support 'inner join' here. Correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE table SET colum=expression [,column = expression ... ]
WHERE condition<br>
```

Read here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10007.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE PEOPLE a
SET a.SURNAME = (
    select b.SURNAME
    from PEOPLE b
    where b.NI.NO = a.NI_NUMBER
)
```